# Importing Scala3 SDK in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to setup Scala3 support for an existing Maven-based project that uses both Java and Scala 2.12. I've updated pom.xml and everything seems fine from maven point of view. However, when I import this project into IDEA (latest build), IDEA is searching for 'scala-library' maven artifact for Scala SDK, while the Scala3 uses 'scala3-library_3' artifact name.

It appears that IDEA simply cannot add Scala3 as SDK (automatically from maven or manually).

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

See/track https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-19068 for the bug in IDEA on this issue.